# How can I see which characters have been removed from file after running tr -cd

Tags: unix, csv, tr

To remove any non-ascii characters from a file, I tried

`tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < original.csv > clean-copy.csv`

I'd like to see the specific characters that were removed from the file, is there any way to print them out? The only thing I can think of is

`diff original.csv clean-copy.csv` but I don't think that is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tr -d '\11\12\15\40-\176' < original.csv
```

will give you all the characters you deleted (same as your original, but without the complement (`-c`).

I suppose you probably wanted them printed out in some more readable format, though; you could try piping that through `hd`.

If you need byte offsets, that's a different question.